# How to Add Active Class to a Navigation Menu Based on URL

Tags: jquery, css

I have problem about this, it can't keep style while it is active. How to Add Active Class to a Navigation Menu Based on URL

```
<div class="admin_nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="admin.php">main</a></li>
        <li><a href="?do=add_menu">manu</a></li>
        <li><a href="?do=add_news">news</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


$(function() {
      var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
      $(".admin_nav ul li a").each(function(){
           if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
           $(this).addClass("newclass");
      })
 });
```

any solution about this????

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for pages that *exactly* end in `/admin.php`, `/?do=add_news` and `/#`

E.g. for the URL `http://example.com/?do=add_news` it will work, but for `http://example.com/foobar.html?do=add_news` it won't work (because of the `foobar` in front of the `?do=add_news`).

If you're only worried about if the final part of the URL *contains* the text in the href fields, you could change your if statement to:

```
if($(this).attr("href") == '' || pgurl.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) > -1)
    $(this).addClass("newclass");
```