# How to add an active class on a current menu item page? html

Tags: javascript, html, menu

How to add an active class on a current menu item page in html header.php .
I added a custom menu in wordpress that is :

```
  <ul class="menuul">
            <li><a href="/#/" class="current">Начало</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#/muskulnamasa/">Действие</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#/sastavki/">Състав</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#/testosteron/">Тестостерон</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#/vuprosi/">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#/mnenia/">Мнения</a></li>
            <li class="lastli"><a href="/#/porachka/">ПОРЪЧАЙ</a></li>
        </ul>
```

So how to add "active" to it?
may be with some javascript?
or PHP?
i did try several answers here in the website:
[i did try this(doesnt work)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623449/how-to-add-active-class-to-a-navigation-menu-based-on-url)

[also i tried this(doesnt work)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33411061/how-to-add-active-class-on-current-menu-item-page)

[and this(no success)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35008942/how-to-add-active-class-to-a-navigation-menu-based-on-url-in-each-page) ; 
[and finally this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44857673/add-active-class-to-menu-item)
Nothing seems to work.
I am probably doing something essential wrong - please help - thanks!

PS:[this didnt work too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789438/how-to-add-active-class-to-wp-nav-menu-current-menu-item-simple-way)

To explain in recap what i need:

I want to add class "active" to the current menu item(current page). Not only to one of the pages, but to any active .
I need something to detect the current page and add a class to it(on the

or on the  element - whatever).

Comment: When you want to add "active" class ?

Comment: doesnt matter, to "a" or to "li" element - i want to add it when the current page is open only to it- like every menu there is...

Answer (score 1):

Just adding on current answers, this is how I did that with vanilla JavaScript:

```
const currentPage = location.href;
const allAs = document.querySelectorAll('a');
const allAsLength = allAs.length

for (let i = 0; i < allAsLength; i++) {
  if ( allAs[i].href === currentPage ) {
    allAs[i].className = "active";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple Css to do that. use active class only on that li. and give the class css, like give it (Font-weight:bold; color:something;...etc). you have seprate pages for every link i guess. so when user goes to that link(that page). only that list will be have class active

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery,

- Place the following code in a common javascript file which can be accessed by all the pages.
- Get the ending of URL and use the same as ID for respected `<a>` element

  ```
  url = window.location.href; //Get the current URL.
  id = url.split("/").splice(-1);
  if(id == ""){
      id = url.split("/").splice(-2); //URL ending with "/"
  }
  if(id != "" || type(id) != "undefined"){
      $(".menuul #"+id).addClass("current");
  }else{
      $(".menuul li:first-child a").addClass("current");
  }
  ```

In your HTML :

```
<ul class="menuul">
          <li><a href="/#/" class="current">Начало</a></li>
          <li><a id="muskulnamasa" href="/#/muskulnamasa/">Действие</a></li>
          <li><a id="sastavki" href="/#/sastavki/">Състав</a></li>
          <li><a id="testosteron" href="/#/testosteron/">Тестостерон</a></li>
          <li><a id="vuprosi" href="/#/vuprosi/">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a id="mnenia" href="/#/mnenia/">Мнения</a></li>
          <li id="porachka" class="lastli"><a href="/#/porachka/">ПОРЪЧАЙ</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS :

Style your `current` CSS class accordingly.

Comment: so i couldn't make it work - i am not sure what you mean in this step:
"Get the ending of URL and use the same as ID for respected <a> element"

Comment: Example for this link `href="/#/sastavki/"`, the URL should end with `/sastavki/`.

Comment: but - i think you misunderstood me.
i want to add class "active" to the current menu item(current page). Not only to one of the pages - this i can do with the html.
I need something to detect the current page and add a class to it.

Comment: `Link1 | Link2 | Link3 | Link4` In this case, you want to add `current` class to `Link3` anchor tag if user is in `Link3` page. Am I right ?

Comment: ` I need something to detect the current page and add a class to it.` >> That code should work.

Comment: yes exactly - but it doesn't...
i putted it in a file menu-active-file.js
and pointed for it in the footer:
  <?php versioned_javascript($GLOBALS["TEMPLATE_RELATIVE_URL"]."/js/menu-active-file.js") ?>

Comment: If you are using chrome, Right click > Inspect Elements > Console. Do you have any errors ?

Comment: nope - its empty - if you want, i can give you the real url, so u can check?

Comment: Ok, Let me check  !

Comment: I see an error in the console. I.e `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .menuul ,`

Comment: well - how to fix it?

Comment: Search for `.menuul ,` and you'll get some idea.  `.menuul ` is a CSS class and it look slike you are using it directly in JavaScript code.

Comment: Try commenting `$(".menuul #"+id).addClass("current");` and ` $(".menuul li:first-child a").addClass("current");` and try alerting the id

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a simple loop through the result of [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
inside the loop you have to compare the href of the element (`<a>` tag) with the [`location.href`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp).

Note that in the example below I have used an hard-coded string instead of [`location.href`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_href.asp) in the example below.

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.menuul > li > a');
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (x[i].href == "https://stacksnippets.net/#/") {
    x[i].className += ' active';
  }
  console.log(i + ' has the classes: ' + x[i].className);
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menuul">
  <li><a href="/#/" class="current">Начало</a></li>
  <li><a href="/#/muskulnamasa/">Действие</a></li>
  <li><a href="/#/sastavki/">Състав</a></li>
  <li><a href="/#/testosteron/">Тестостерон</a></li>
  <li><a href="/#/vuprosi/">FAQ</a></li>
  <li><a href="/#/mnenia/">Мнения</a></li>
  <li class="lastli"><a href="/#/porachka/">ПОРЪЧАЙ</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this didnt work too - hmmm ... what i am doing wrong?

Comment: @PlamenRashkov are you sure the javascript runs on every page in your website?

Answer (score 0):

ohh - it took me 4-5 hours to find it, so ...
i paste the answer here- may be some1 can use it.
i putted the following code in a file menu-active-file.js and pointed for it in the footer:

```
 $(function () {
    var url = window.location.pathname,
urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/, '') + "$");  
    $('a').each(function () {
                        if (urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/, ''))) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for all the answers anyway.